# Netbeans Platform & Perspective?

Tags: swing, netbeans-platform

Anyone had to program a **perspective control** with ability to **setup the position of several views** for Netbeans?

Do you know any libraries or have other info?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geertjan recently introduced this on his blog ([here](http://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/roles_profiles_perspectives_in_netbeans) and [here](http://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/multi_level_security_via_roles)) but my understanding is that it will only be avalable in NetBeans 7.1

In the mean time there is a [contrib module](http://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/the_case_for_profiles_part) that Geertjan mentions that should put you on the road until roles(the NetBeans name for perspectives becomes available).

Also I'm not sure if this relates to what you're asking but NetBeans 7.1 is also going to introduce a [Visual Designer](http://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/visual_editor_for_window_system) for laying out modes.